# The maps $f_+$ and $f_-$ are well-defined.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, polynomial-rings

> We define the maps $f_+$ and $f_-$ from $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2 -2) \mathbb{Q}[X]$ to $\mathbb{Q} + \mathbb{Q} \cdot \sqrt2$ in the following manner: For any residue class $g+ (X^2-2) \mathbb{Q}[X]$, we write:

$$ f_+(g+ (X^2-2) \mathbb{Q}[X]) = g \left( \sqrt2 \right)$$

$$ f_-(g+ (X^2-2) \mathbb{Q}[X]) = g \left(- (\sqrt2) \right)$$

I want to show that these maps are **well-defined**.
Because the degree of our polynomial $X^2-1$ is two, every representative in the residue class will have a degree less than this, upon division. We thus expect polynomials  in the domain of the form $aX+b$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$; the elements in the image will have the form $p+ q \sqrt2$, with $p,q \in \mathbb{Q}$.

I have a hard time figuring out what this map precisely does to elements in the domain. If I would understand this, it might be easier to prove it is well-defined ( it does not matter which representative we pick).

Comment: No need to write $\;(x^2-2)\Bbb Q[x]\;$ , enough with $\;(x^2-2)\;$ to denote the polynomial ideal, otherwise both the writing and the reading become cumbersome

Comment: There are infinitely many rational numbers. The same holds for the extension field present in this question. Therefore the tag [tag:finite-fields] was inappropriate.

Comment: To get started on the question. What are the potential sources of non-well-definedness here? You should notice that on the right hand side a polynomial $g$ is evaluated at a point. Yet, look at the left hand side, we seek to define the image of a **coset of an ideal of polynomials**. In other words, the polynomial $g$ is simply a **representative** of its coset. What could go wrong, if we use some other polynomial to represent the coset?

Comment: Compare: the "definition" of a function $f:\Bbb{Z}/5\Bbb{Z}\to\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$ by the recipe $f(\overline{n})=\overline{n}$ does not work. It is not well-defined, because the result of the function depends on the choice of integer $n$ representing the coset $\overline{n}\in\Bbb{Z}/5\Bbb{Z}$. For example, $0$ and $5$ belong to the same coset (or residue class) of integers modulo five. In other words $\overline{0}=\overline{5}$ in the domain. If $f$ is to be a function we need $f(\overline{0})=f(\overline{5})$.

Comment: (cont'd) But in the codomain $\overline{0}\neq\overline{5}$ because $0$ and $5$ are not congruent to each other modulo four. Therefore this recipe does not give a well-defined function. A point of this exercise is to study what happens to polynomials. Remember that the cosets $g+(x^2-2)$ and $g'+(x^2-2)$ belong to the same coset of the ideal $(x^2-2)$ if their difference $g-g'$ is a (polynomial) multiple of $x^2-2$. The key point is whether this matters at all in the definition of $f_+$ or $f_-$?

Comment: For any two elements $g , g'$ in the same coset, we have that $g= g' +k (X^2-2)$ for some polynomial $k$.  If we plug this into our function, we get that  $f_\pm(g) =g(\sqrt{2})= g' (\sqrt{2}) \pm k ((\sqrt{2})^2 -2)= g ' (\sqrt{2})$, which should be the case. It is well-defined.

Comment: Similarly whenever $ f_\pm(z)= f_\pm (y) \implies z(\pm\sqrt{2})= y( \pm\sqrt{2}) $. This means that these outputs are the same, so after applying the function we have $z(\pm\sqrt2)=y(\pm \sqrt2)= a(\pm \sqrt{2})+b$. This can only be the case  if $z$ and $y$ had the same representation $aX+b$ in the first place, so $z=y$.

Comment: Finally, for surjectivity, we want to be able to obtain any output of the form $p+q (\pm \sqrt{2})$. If we let our input be $g=p+qX$ we get that $f_\pm(g)=p+q(\pm \sqrt{2}) $. Consequently the functions are surjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tip in the comments answered my question.  The function is well-defined because any equivalent elements $g$ and $g'$ have images $g(\pm \sqrt{2})$ and $ g'(\pm \sqrt{2})$.

Comment: Correct. Well done!